# Xcode: Certificate errors

Tags: xcode, distribution, certificate

I added a new feature into an app which I'm updating for the app store. When I tried to run it on my iPhone, I ran into a popup error saying "A valid provisioning profile for this executable". So, I went into the organizer, and both my Developer and Distribution profile are both active and showing up just fine. So, I tried re-adding my developer and distribution certs to the Keychain Access. I noticed 2 duplicates in there, and they only stated my first and last name. I deleted one of each. Now, when I try to run the program, it says "Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain". One of the files I accidentally deleted in the Keychain Access was probably my private key.

I tried re-adding each one agin in the Keychain Access. My provisioning profiles are both showing up in the Organizer as well. Where should I go from here?

Thank you!

Edit: I checked the profiles again in the organizer, and when I highlight my distribution profile, it says "Xcode could not find a private key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to recreate your public & private key pair (if you didn't have them backed up anywhere) and then recreate your provisioning profiles.  A pain to do, but the profiles are tied to your keys.

Comment: Ah bummer, alright I'll go ahead and do that. I actually do have time machine running, but haven't found those keys anywhere. Do you know where they are stored? Thank you.

Comment: Check out [this Apple discussion about Time Machine & keychains](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1413307?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: Okay thank you. I ended up just deleting and reading the provisioning profiles. Can distribution profiles be installed on devices? I have to change the code signing to "Development" rather than "Distribution" to get it to run on my iPhone. And, should I set it back to "Distribution" when I submit to the app store? Sorry for asking so many questions, I'm still really new at this.

Comment: you can have both Development and Distribution profiles for your devices.